# how to output with group by specific fields in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

there is a collection in MongoDB,

Ex:-

```
{ field1: a, field2: 1, field3: val_1, field4: val_11}
{ field1: a, field2: 2, field3: val_2, field4: val_22}
{ field1: a, field2: 5, field3: val_3, field4: val_33}
{ field1: a, field2: 1, field3: val_4, field4: val_44}
{ field1: a, field2: 3, field3: val_5, field4: val_55}
{ field1: a, field2: 3, field3: val_6, field4: val_66}
{ field1: a, field2: 5, field3: val_7, field4: val_77}
{ field1: a, field2: 2, field3: val_8, field4: val_88}
{ field1: a, field2: 1, field3: val_9, field4: val_99}
{ field1: a, field2: 2, field3: val_10, field4: val_1010}
{ field1: a, field2: 3, field3: val_11, field4: val_1111}
{ field1: b, field2: 3, field3: val_12, field4: val_1212}
{ field1: b, field2: 3, field3: val_13, field4: val_1313}
{ field1: b, field2: 3, field3: val_14, field4: val_1414}
{ field1: b, field2: 3, field3: val_15, field4: val_1515}
```

I want to query the collection and output of the document group by the field:-

Ex:- get the document where the `field1` is `a` group by `field2` values

```
{ field1: a, field2: 1, field3: val_1, field4: val_11}
{ field1: a, field2: 1, field3: val_4, field4: val_44}
{ field1: a, field2: 1, field3: val_9, field4: val_99}

{ field1: a, field2: 2, field3: val_2, field4: val_22}
{ field1: a, field2: 2, field3: val_8, field4: val_88}
{ field1: a, field2: 2, field3: val_10, field4: val_1010}

{ field1: a, field2: 5, field3: val_3, field4: val_33}
{ field1: a, field2: 5, field3: val_7, field4: val_77} 

{ field1: a, field2: 3, field3: val_5, field4: val_55}
{ field1: a, field2: 3, field3: val_6, field4: val_66} 
{ field1: a, field2: 3, field3: val_11, field4: val_1111}
```

I tried to use the `$group` in `aggregate` but unable to achieve the expected output

how to achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$match` will filter out the documents where `field1` is not equal to `a`.

`$group` will group the data followed by the expression in `_id` and `$push` the `$$ROOT` document in data field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "field1": "a" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$field2",
    "data": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: @rahulKushwaha Updated my answer.

Comment: using aggregate operator is difficult for me, Can you also sort each group by the `field3`?

Comment: MongoDB offers a full free online training course on the aggregation framework, https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about.

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole Why did you share? Any reason?

Comment: The author said he was having difficulties with the aggregation framework ("using the aggregate operator is difficult for me"). This free training may help him overcome his difficulties.